# MySQL Running Total return empty values

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, window-functions

```
table values
------
100
50
100
50
```

```
<?php
$sth = $DB->prepare('
    SELECT  ( @runnningtotal :=  @runnningtotal + values) FROM table 
    ');
$sth->execute();


print("All rows:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

what is the problem on my code ? why @runnningtotal return empty values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  need to initialize the variable first; you can do that with a `SET` command before running the query, or within the query with a `CROSS JOIN`.

Also, in order to get a stable result, you need a column that defines the ordering in which rows should be processed (I represented it as `id` in the query) - and I would recommend pre-sort the values in a subquery first:

```
SELECT @runnningtotal := @runnningtotal + t.val as running_sum
FROM (SELECT val FROM mytable ORDER BY id) t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @runnningtotal := 0) r
```

User variables are planned for deprecation in a future MySQL version. Meanwhile, MySQL 8.0 added window functions, which make this task much easier and more efficient:

```
SELECT SUM(val) OVER(ORDER BY id) running_sum
FROM mytable
```

Comment: you save my day, thank you very much. I added only `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @runnningtotal := 0) x` and it works.